# How to display images from S3 bucket using Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-s3, xcode7

I am using an Amazon S3 bucket to save images and it was working fine in Xcode 6 but after upgrading to Xcode 7 the app is not displaying the images. But when I enabled the `NSAppTransportSecurity` security and it is working fine.

How can I get it to work without app transport security?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 app download from Amazon S3 SSL error: TLS 1.2 support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500655/ios-9-app-download-from-amazon-s3-ssl-error-tls-1-2-support)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add an exception for the server hosting your images, or allow all arbitrary loads to your app's plist file.  `NSAppTransportSecurity` is required for iOS 9 and above.

Exception:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>download.yourServer.com.s3.amazonaws.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Allow all connections:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```